# how can get id value of a parent div at the time of dragging child div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing  code of drag and drop. I want to  drag a child `div` from a parent div to another parent div, how can I get the value of id of parent div and the id of another parent div where the draggable child div are dropped .
I am writing code below.

```html
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("ter", $(this).closest("div"));
    var topi = $(this).closest("div");
    console.log('draggable= ' + topi)
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    var divid = ev.dataTransfer.getData("ter").toString();
    // var divid=$(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
    var topi = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('sss ' + topi);

    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertData.action",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            // console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <s:if test="inlist.size>0">
        <%
            int k = 1;
        %>
        <s:iterator id="sl" value="inlist">
            <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id='<s:property value="id"/>' width="88" height="31">
                <li>
                    <s:property value="name"/>
                </li>
            </div>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:if>
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

and I am attaching the image

[image]

in that image every name like ganesh is under draggable child div and looking like box(total 3) is droppable parent `div`.

Comment: Can you make SO Fiddle with actual rendered content?

Comment: SO fiddle means?i am not getting the point.

Comment: The thing that you put your code in (this big pop-up with JS/HTML/CSS panels)

Comment: i am not putting any panel ,this is the single page project and i posted all those thing from page in this question

Comment: In THIS QUESTION where you show your HTML: Replace all your parsable content with actual HTML and not `<% int k = 1 %>`

Comment: <% int k = 1 %> this is not related to my question ,i am using this is for for back end (java) for this and <s:if> ans <s:iteretot> i got the value like ganesh in draggable div,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `drag(ev)`, `this` is the `window`. Use `$(ev.target).closest("div")`:

```
function drag(ev) {
    var dragDivId = $(ev.target).closest("div")[0].parentElement.id;
    console.log(dragDivId);
}

function drop(ev) {
    var dropDivId = ev.target.id;
    console.log(dropDivId);
}
```